# How would i set order of MVCLister?

Tags: php, atk4

How would i properly sort output of a MVClister?

```
<?php
class page_index extends Page {
    function init(){
    parent::init();
    $p=$this;

    $this->add('MVCLister',null,'News','News')->setModel('News');
    $this->add('MVCLister',null,'Links','Links')->setModel('Links');

    }

    function defaultTemplate(){
        return array('page/home');  // separate pages from views to avoid mess in templates
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can order either through model or by using lister's dq property. Model ordering would be a more global decision such as News probably should be ordered within the model:

```
// class Model_News, inside init() function
$this->setOrder(null, 'id', true);
```

If it is a user-interface condition, such as a link passed through GET, then you should apply order directly on MVCLister:

```
$list = $this->add('MVCLister');
$list->setModel('Links');
$list->dq->order('popularity desc');
```